# How to show the convergence of this infinite series: $\frac{x}{1+x}- \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+ \frac{x^3}{1+x^3}\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

My series is 
$$
\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+ \frac{x^3}{1+x^3}-.....
$$

Given: $0<x<1$

I see that my nth term is $(-1)^{n+1} (\frac{x^n}{1+x^n})$

My approach was to use Dirichlet's test. I see that $\frac1{1+x^n}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence converging to $0$.

So, I need to show that the partial sum sequences of the series $(-1)^{n+1} (x^n)$ is bounded. Is it true?

If not, how do I approach this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, is the general term $\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}$?

Comment: Aren't you working with another alternating series again?

Comment: Yes, I've been working with a lot of infinite series, lol. I got the last one, I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: Learn to use LaTeX

Comment: Just show the terms are going to zero and apply the alternating series test.

Comment: I mean this is also an alternating series with Leibniz's test

Comment: @Shahar sorry, I'm new, I messed it up! Edited it though. I think I get LaTex now. Thanks :)

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you! But is my approach with Dirichlet Test wrong? I know it's complicated, but is it correct?

Comment: It is correct, just more complicated. Just note that $x^n\to 0$ and you can write the series $\sum(-1)^{n+1}x^n$ explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your infinite series is absolutely convergent:
$$
\left| \frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+ \frac{x^3}{1+x^3}-....\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{x}{1-x}, \quad 0<x<1.
$$